# Autowired returns null in spring boot

Tags: java, spring

Following is the application any pointers where the error is

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAutoWApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringAutoWApplication.class, args);
    DestClass dc = new DestClass();
    dc.showTestWired();
  }
}



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
@Component
public class DestClass {

@Autowired
private TestWired testWired;

public void showTestWired() {
    System.out.println(testWired.getTestInt());
}

}
```

Class to be autowired

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


 @Component
public class TestWired {

 int testInt = 234;

public int getTestInt() {
    return testInt;
}

public void setTestInt(int testInt) {
    this.testInt = testInt;
}
}
```

Error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
       at DestClass.showTestWired(DestClass.java:13)

the line where i am trying to call the print the int is returning a null pointer exception

**Answer:** After few hours of looking around **this is the way it works**, as I cannot post my answer I am doing it here

```
public class SpringAutoWApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringAutoWApplication.class, args);
    DestClass dc = context.getBean(DestClass.class);
    dc.showTestWired();
 }
```

}

Comment: Ok here goes the answer for this
    ` ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringAutoWApplication.class, args);
     DestClass dc = context.getBean(DestClass.class);`


With this you can create autowire.

Answer (score 1):

Autowire only work on spring bean.

Your `DestClass` is not a bean. Hence no autowire occur, @Autowire has no effect.

Mark your `DestClass` with `@Component` will do it:

```
@Component
public class DestClass {
```

Moreover, you're initialize your own instance, not get from spring bean so your test bean is null:

```
   DestClass dc = new DestClass();
```

Instead, autowire `DestClass` in your `SpringAutoWApplication` class.

```
@Autowired
DestClass dc;
```

Finally it can be test like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAutoWApplication {

 @Bean
 String test(DestClass dc) {
    dc.showTestWired();
    return "work";
 }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringAutoWApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too still the same error

Comment: See my edited asnwer

Comment: Still its null  
`@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAutoWApplication {
 @Autowired
 static
 DestClass dc;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SpringAutoWApplication.class, args);
  dc.showTestWired();
 }
}`

Comment: Remove the `static` modifier on `DestClass`. Can't autowire static field.

Comment: If I remove static from a static main I cannot reference a non static variable.

Comment: Yes, of course. If you cannot set up another class for test. Define a `@Bean` method.  `@Bean String getString(DestClass dc) { dc. showTestWired(); return "work";}`

Comment: And how do I call that?

Comment: No need to call, @Bean method will be called upon start. Try it

Comment: Still a error, Is it working for you, can you pelase try and let me know SpringAutoWApplication.main(SpringAutoWApplication.java:17)

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: though it prints .. does that mean I cannot use these in any other classes apart from the main spring class?
Also if I need multiple classes to be autowired all has to be defined in only one class?

Comment: You can wire your `DestClass` in all bean class (annotated with @Component, @Service...). You can freely use them. My example is just used to show how it works.

Comment: What I was trying is using `TestWired`  class as a autowired inside the `DestClass`, I want the `DestClass` to be normal and call methods on it as my starting string application in the question shows. `DestClass dc = new DestClass(); dc.showTestWired();`  Can you let me know how I can do that?

Comment: You cannot do that. You have to make DestClass a bean to autowire.

Comment: Adding @Component should make it a bean? or what are the other ways to make it a bean

Comment: I have posted the answer. Thanks a lot for your support and help!